# Receiving a Spring RequestMappingHandlerMapping error in Google App Engine

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, spring-bean

I have built a simple Spring MVC application that works flawlessly on my local machine. Having uploaded it to the Google App Engine, however, I receive a HTTP 500 error.

Looking into the logs I recieve this `INFO` message:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/enterprise-servlet.xml]
```

Which is normal, as I receive this `INFO` message when running the app locally. Spring would then go onto map urls onto methods, for example a log message from my local machine:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/listStaff],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json || application/xml]}" onto public java.util.List<org.andrewvincent.model.Staff> org.andrewvincent.controller.Controller.listStaffXML()
```

However when looking at the logs from the app engine, I receive the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext refresh: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessClassInPackage.sun.reflect.annotation")
```

I assume this is why I am receiving the 500 error code, as the urls are not being mapped onto the methods, but I cannot work out why I receive this error when I don't locally.

The following is my enterprise-servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="controllerBean" class="org.andrewvincent.controller.Controller"></bean>
    <bean id="plainControllerBean"
      class="org.andrewvincent.controller.PlainTextController"></bean>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
</beans>
```

If anyone could help me out it would be much appreciated.

Comment: What version of Spring are you using?

Comment: @NielsMasdorp I'm using version 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known [bug](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13829).

Are you using 4.2.4? If so you should downgrade to 4.2.3.